# Discord.py on_message() missing arguments with @client.event

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_message(ctx,x,op,y):
    if ctx.content.startswith("?!solve"):
         if op == "+":
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=("Solved!"),
            description=("Problem: " + str(x + " + " + y + " \n\n") + "Answer: " + str(int(x) + int(y))),
            colour=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        elif op == "-":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=("Solved!"),
                description=("Problem: " + str(x + " - " + y + " \n\n") + "Answer: " + str(int(x) -      int(y))),
            colour=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        elif op == "x" or "×":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=("Solved!"),
                description=("Problem: " + str(x + " x " + y + " \n\n") + "Answer: " + str(int(x) * int(y))),
                colour=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        elif op == "/":
            embed = discord.Embed(
               title=("Solved!"),
                description=("Problem: " + str(x + " / " + y + " \n\n") + "Answer: " + str(int(x) / int(y))),
                colour=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        else:
            await ctx.send("Wrong Argument")

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

it keeps saying x,op,y are missing arguments, and Im using @client.event
cause flask ignores @client.commands()...and maybe your wondering why I needed flask, I use flask for 24/7 bot hosting so... pls help me

Answer (score 0):

It's an event, you only pass **ONE** argument, `message`, if you want all the other ones you need to use a command

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): # Only this argument
    ...
    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def foo(ctx, x, op, y):
    ...
```

Comment: well you need to fix that, or split the message content but it's not possible to add additional parameters to an event